# CakeEmail is erroneously reporting that a template is missing when using themes

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.7, cakeemail

I have a controller `QuickContacts` with an action `add()` which uses `CakeEmail` to send a message, like so:

```
$Email = new CakeEmail();
$Email->from(array('noreply@xyz' => 'xyz'));
$Email->to(($this->isBranded) ? $this->brandedAccount['BrandedAccount']['contact_us_email'] : EMAIL_TO_MAIL_ADDRESS);
$Email->subject(EMAIL_QUICK_CONTACTS_SUBJECT);
$Email->emailFormat('html')->template('add', 'default');
$Email->message($this->request->data);

$Email->send();
```

When I try and send the mail, I get an error indicating that a view file does not exist:

```
Missing View
Error: The view for QuickContactsController::add() was not found.

Confirm you have created the file: Emails/html/add.ctp  in one of the following paths:

/var/www/html/mysite/app/View/Themed/Xyz/Emails/html/add.ctp
```

I can certainly confirm those files exist, but for some reason CakePHP still is unable to find them, and I can't figure out why this might be happening. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please post your exact CakePHP version

Comment: @InigoFlores Hi, it is version 2.7, I should add I have just recently upgraded to 2.7 from 1.3.

Comment: Just to rule it out, have you checked that 
`/var/www/html/mysite/app/View/Themed/Xyz/Emails/html/add.ctp` is readable by Apache?

Comment: Also, you may need to set the theme in CakeEmail -  `$Email->theme('xyz')` as described in [Sending Templated Emails](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#sending-templated-emails).

Comment: @InigoFlores Thanks the theme setting has resolved the issue! I really didn't find that clearly communicated in the documentation.

Comment: Great! I will make the comment into an answer so that it can be approved.

Comment: Do one thing make a new ctp lets newsletter.ctp ,put  it in this path projectname/app/View/Layouts/Emails/html   ,here place your template of mail format   and create another ctp file same as previous name in projectname/app/View/Emails/html  ,copy the code of default.ctp present in this above path into this. just add this line to your controller  $mail->template('newsletter', 'newsletter');  and try is it working or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitly set the theme in `CakeEmail`:

```
$Email->theme('xyz')
```

as described in the Cookboox 2.x: [Sending Templated Emails](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#sending-templated-emails).

The error message is pointing you towards the correct path, but CakePHP is  looking for your file in:

```
/app/Emails/html/add.ctp
```

This may be due to a bug.